# Is there a regular ferry between Sicily and Sardinia? (first hand experience)

Tags: italy, ferries

I would like to know from somebody, with **first hand experience**, that has traveled from Sicily to Sardinia using a ferry (within the last 2 years).

Is there a regular ferry? And how regular (once a week, daily, ...)

---

Here is the information I found on the internet.

According to [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=ferry+sicily+to+sardinia&source=hp&ei=j4DYYMa_DIvQUpK9voAG&iflsig=AINFCbYAAAAAYNiOn4Ajp4lhUBCkhEbLYnNat2G3FYU0&oq=ferry+sicily+to+sardinia&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyAggAMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB46CAgAELEDEIMBOgUIABCxAzoOCC4QsQMQgwEQxwEQrwE6CAguELEDEIMBOgsILhCxAxCDARCTAjoLCC4QsQMQxwEQrwE6CAguEMcBEK8BOggILhDHARCjAjoLCAAQsQMQgwEQyQM6CwguELEDEMcBEKMCOgIILjoRCC4QsQMQgwEQxwEQrwEQkwI6BQgAEMkDOgUIABCSA1CLCVjTPGCNPmgAcAB4AIABwwGIAZIbkgEEMC4yNJgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXo&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwiGw6T9-LfxAhULqBQKHZKeD2AQ4dUDCAY&uact=5) there are ferries but I would like to get some first hand reports.

On [Southern Ferries](http://www.sncm.co.uk/index.htm) there seem to be 2 ferries a week (in summer at least).

On [tirrenia](https://en.tirrenia.it/) I found a ferry between Sicily (Palermo) and Naples.

On [grimaldi lines](https://www.grimaldi-lines.com/en/) they are advertising a new line from Palermo (Sicily) - Cagliari (Sardinia) - Naples but they only provide details for Cagliari - Naples.

Google maps and [openstreetmaps](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=8/38.857/10.956) show routes but I am not sure what that means

[image]

Comment: If you use Google maps to get directions from one island to another, one of the steps will be to take the ferry, which at the very least tells you the name of that ferry route. Maybe you'll get more relevant results (eg, how to buy a ticket, and contact info for the ferry line so you can make sure it's actually still running) by googling the specific ferry route name.

Comment: If you go to the Southern Ferries page you are linking to (which btw is just a booking company and not a ferry operator), they will find and sell you tickets to the Palermo-Cagliari ferry operated by Grimaldi Lines. Do you expect that to be a scam or what exactly do you need to get confirmed from people with first hand experience onboard this ferry?

Comment: The Grimaldi Lines website does indeed show details for [regular scheduled ferries between Cagliari and Palermo](https://www.grimaldi-lines.com/en/route/palermo-cagliari/#prenota).

Comment: As Tor-Einar Jarnbjo says, a timetable and someone willing to sell you a ticket is far more reliable than first-hand experience. Transport in Europe has been seriously disrupted over the past year, with many tourist routes suspended and restrictions frequently changing, so I wouldn't depend on personal experience (although even a booking isn't a guarantee of travel in the current environment).

Answer (score 1):

The ferry from Palermo to Cagliari takes you about 11 hours. It runs two times per week. It's from Grimaldi, the reviews are not that positive, unfortunately.